# InvocationTargetException from web service which returns a custom object

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I am migrating a web application from a websphere environment to tomcat7 & Axis2. I have a number of web services which are causing me problems.

The web services are created from a Java class using the web services wizard in eclipse (Juno). The appropriate folders are created under WEB-INF/services and the application is able the call the services. Services which return simple objects (String, int etc) work fine. Services which return a custom object (e.g. Customer, Country) generate an error response which contains the following:

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</faultstring>
<detail/>
```

The custom objects are serialisable and have a public null constructor. Just as a test I changed the return type to String and added toString() to the return value - it worked.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: You must at least log the full stacktrace and post it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - that is partly my problem. The only logs I can find are the access logs. There is no exception in my code so there's nothing to log. Does Axis have its' own logging?

Comment: @paul See my answer, on how to configure the LogHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get some logging from Axis2, I was able to add the following to my log4j.xml:

```
<category name="org.apache.axis2" additivity="false">
    <priority value="trace"/>
    <appender-ref ref="roller"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</category>
```

I was then able to see that the root cause of the **InvocationTargetException** was a NullPointerException in one of my classes. Axis2 seems to be more sensitive to such things than Axis1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Axis2, probably something similar, but in order to debug such issues, with Axis, I would add the LogHandler in WSDD file. This way you will see the exception that was causing this. For tomcat see [How to log SOAP messages for a Tomcat/Axis Web Service](http://blogmines.com/blog/2007/02/09/how-to-log-soap-messages-for-a-tomcataxis-web-service/)

For Axis2 you need to write a simple module, see [Writing Your Own Axis2 Module](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/modules.html#Step2_%3a_LogHandler).

Comment: I don't have a WSDD file. I *think* that was just for Axis1 but I may be wrong.

Comment: @paul It seems that Axis2 is using a different approach. See my updated answer.